# How to get a string name to resolve to an object (i.e. in the sense of what it is)

Tags: c#, oop, factory

For example I can do something like:

```
switch (myString)
case "rectangle":
 o = new rect();
 break;
case "ellipse"
 etc...
```

but how do I not do the above, i.e. just have one line of code that gets the object directly from the string.  Imagine, for example, a button and whatever it says when the user clicks it, it takes the displayed text and creates an object from it.

Comment: What do you want to do with the instance after you create it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the name is the *exact* same thing as the string, you can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, "Example").Unwrap();
    }
}
```

A simpler approach would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Example");
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this is a *very* simple example that doesn't involve namespaces, strong-named assemblies, or any other complicated things that crop up in bigger projects.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Activator.CreateInstace(Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx)
or [Activator.CreateInstance(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: There is no `CreateInstance` overload that accepts just a type name.

Answer (score 1):

He descf,

Have you tried Activator.CreateInstace("assemblyname", "typename");

Comment: There is no `CreateInstance` overload that accepts just a type name.

Answer (score 0):

A [Factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386125/real-world-examples-of-factory-method-pattern) would decouple the code from the string. Please take a look at this [dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) page for both the UML and a C# example of the Factory pattern.