# OO - Creating object using a method of no argument

Tags: java, oop

I am experience some problems in understanding how the OO pattern works, My lecturer gave me the following question but I cannot solve it after thinking whole day

Scenario for my problems.

There is a class named "ShapeManager" which manages the Shape object. A class named "Shape" has two subclasses named "**Circle**" and "**Rectangle**"

The implementation of **Shape** class as follow

```
abstract public class Shape {
    private String id;
    private double length;

    public Shape() {

    }
    public Shape(String id , double length) {
        this.id = id;
        this.length = length;
    }
    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public abstract String getDetails();

}
```

The subclass **Square** as follow

```
public class Square extends Shape{

    public Square() {
        super();
   }
    public Square(String id , double side) {
        super(id, side);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        return "Square => Id : "+getID() +", Side : "+ getLength() + ",Area : "+(getLength() * getLength());
    }
}
```

The subclass **Circle** as follow

```
public class Circle extends Shape{
    public Circle(){
        super();
    }
    public Circle (String id, double radius) {
        super(id, radius);

    }

    @Override
    public String details() {        
        return "Circle => Id : "+getID() + ", Radius : "+ getLength() + ",Area: "+(3.14*(getLength() * getLength()));
    }
}
```

The **ShapeManager** class as follow, this is not a completed class

```
public class ShapeManager {
    public Shape createShape() {

    }
    public void updateLength(String id ){

    }
    public void deleteShape(String id) {

    }
    public void listShapes() {

    }

}
```

**ShapeManager** have an association with **Shape**

```
 ShapeManager --1------0..*--> Shape
```

The design of this package (All the classes above) can not be changed, implementation must be following OCP (Open-Closed Principle).

My question is: How am I suppose to complete createShape method? Without parameter, it is seemingly impossible to create an object either a Rectangle or Circle.

Comment: @subash sounds like if its possible without arguments

Comment: I think it is clear in my last line of this question?

Comment: Tell your lecturer that `Manager` is a terrible name for a `Factory`!

Comment: What's missing is what that `createShape` method is supposed to do.

Comment: It said that it's an incomplete class. Narendra, ShapeManager isn't just a factory, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @iccthedral not exactly a factory, but still a bad convention IMHO.

Comment: Add an argument to the factory method (createShape). Btw OOP = Object Oriented Programming, not pattern.

Comment: @JuniorProgrammer Shouldn't class ShapeManager have a list of shapes as a member ? Because it seems that function createShape is adding a new shape to the list ,also update and delete and listShapes have something to do with that list, and so createShape should have a parameter to determine what is the subclass ?

Comment: @T-D It should have a Vector or ArrayList, I forgot to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShapeManager cannot create a shape if not knowing what this shape is (Square, Circle or something else). And it really doesn't know because you say the method createShare has no parameters. Either you misunderstood the question or the lecturer didn't explain it well. You should ask him/her for clarifications. If you look at the libraries of Java or any other OO language, I am pretty sure you won't find such scenario and implementation pattern as the one you gave in your example.

---

@croraf

You should find some other reading I think e.g. the classic book [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612). The main idea of a factory is that it returns something whose type the caller doesn't know, and doesn't care about. For example, if you have a method createSocket() in some SocketFactory, this method is usually defined to return an interface or an abstract class Socket. But actually it returns **new SocketImpl1()** and new **SocketImpl2()** which are concrete classes. What the factory returns may depend on many things - a system property, the underlying OS, anything you can think of. The main idea is that the factory centralizes the creation of Socket objects at one single place. This way, if you need to make a change, you can make it just in the factory. I think this book also has some decent Java counterparts too, you may look around. Other free good sources are referenced here.

[Real world examples of Factory Method pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386125/real-world-examples-of-factory-method-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have something like this, similar to how BorderFactory from java API works.

```
public class ShapeManager {
    public Shape createCircle() {
            ...
            return Circle;
    }
     public Shape createSquare() {
            ....
            return Square;
    }
      ...

   public void updateLength(String id ){

}
public void deleteShape(String id) {

}
public void listShapes() {

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for my first +1 :). I was yesterday trying to understand static factory methods, and this is the 3rd point from explanation of their usefullness(am i right?). http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21. But can you explain to me how to finish this pattern.

Comment: Good that you're willing to learn and willing to learn it well. I gave you another upvote and added something for you in my response.

Comment: Ty sir for your explanation, +1.
I took http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1385822000&sr=1-2&keywords=design+patterns, hope they are about the same thing, and have a chapter about this pattern?

Comment: I hope so too. See also here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331/best-book-resource-for-learning-java-design-patterns Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create shape without knowing type which shape would You like to create. You can define enumeration for types and pass the type value to the `createShape()`. And there You can switch between types and create the concrette shape You want.

Comment: I was just saying the same. So I agree. This task/assignment doesn't look correctly stated to me too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Its classic `Factory pattern`.

```
public class ShapeFactory {
  public abstract Shape getShape(int shapeId);
}

 public interface Const {
  public static final int SHAPE_CIRCLE =1;
  public static final int SHAPE_SQUARE =2; 
}


public class SimpleShapeFactory extends ShapeFactory throws BadShapeException {
   public Shape getShape(int shapeTypeId){
    Shape shape = null;
    if(shapeTypeId == Const.SHAPE_CIRCLE) {

    //in future can reuse or cache objects.
      shape = new Circle();
    }
    else if(shapeTypeId == Const.SHAPE_SQUARE) {
      //in future can reuse or cache objects
      shape = new Square();
     }
    else throw new BadShapeException("ShapeTypeId="+ shapeTypeId);
    return shape;
  }
}
```

Calling:

```
ShapeFactory factory = new SimpleShapeFactory();

//returns a Shape but whether it is a Circle or a
//Square is not known to the caller.
Shape s = factory.getShape(1);
s.getDetails(); // circle details called
//returns a Shape but whether it is a Circle or a
//Square is not known to the caller.
s = factory.getShape(2);
s.getDetails(); //Square details called
```

*References*:

> The **[Open Close Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html)** states that the design and writing of the code should be done in a way that new functionality should be added with **minimum changes** in the existing code. The design should be done in a way to allow the adding of new functionality as new classes, keeping as much as possible existing code unchanged.

Comment: I think added a link to the resource where you extracted the definition of open/closed principle would improve the response