# Scenarios where we can use factory pattern in real projects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am learning design pattern. It is well explained in tutorial but I have some confusion. Kindly experts guide me.
In this example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGqw8crGZ7Y&list=PL6n9fhu94yhUbctIoxoVTrklN3LMwTCmd&index=8)
he explained contract and permanent employee.
But I think we can do that work with database.
Am thinking right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Real world examples of Factory Method pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386125/real-world-examples-of-factory-method-pattern)

Comment: This is good example but this is again coding level example.
I am thinking about the work which can be done by database why we are using there factory pattern. May be I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory Method Pattern is used when
• a class can't anticipate the class of objects it must create.
• a class wants its subclasses to specify the objects it creates.
• classes delegate responsibility to one of several helper subclasses, and you want to localize the knowledge of which helper subclass is the delegate.

The Factory Method Pattern is useful if you’ve only got one concrete creator because you are decoupling the implementation of the product from its use. If you add additional products or change a product’s implementation, it will not affect your Creator (because the Creator is not tightly coupled to any ConcreteProduct).

I think [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFVTgRHJLM&t) explains it really good.